# C++ Seeking advice on alphabetically sorting strings inputted via ifstream BEFORE storing in array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, stream

I've spent the morning working out how to read in words from a .txt file and store them in a dynamic array. However my objective is to sort the words alphabetically as they are inputted. I've done as much research in to finding an answer as possible but cannot find a solution.

I am aware that the dynamic array is currently taking a predetermined value, but that's not important for now.

I'm just looking for some direction, anything would be great. This is what I have so far:

**ARRAYSTORAGE.CPP**

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include "ArrayStorage.h"
using namespace std;


void ArrayStorage::read(ifstream &fin1)
{
    int index = 0;
    string firstTwo;
    const int arrayLength = 4160;

    string* arrayOfWords;
    arrayOfWords = new string[arrayLength];

    if(fin1.is_open())
        {
            fin1 >> firstTwo;
            fin1 >> firstTwo;
            while(!fin1.eof())
            {
                fin1 >> arrayOfWords[index];
                cout << arrayOfWords[index];
                cout << "\n";
                index++;
            }

            delete [] arrayOfWords;

            fin1.close();
        }
}
```

**HEADER.CPP**

//presumed irrelevant

**MAIN.CPP**

//presumed irrelevant

Thanks!

Comment: using an array, that's going to require some work moving values around as you push them in. do you **have** to use an array?

Comment: Unfortunately yes I HAVE to use an array, and I HAVE to sort them before they are stored. I know it's a nightmare!

Comment: If you are allowed to switch data structures, I recommend using a list or a binary tree.  These data structures have fast modification times.  Search the web for "insert sort linked list".

Comment: Thanks Thomas I will check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put them in set/multiset (former if you can have duplicates), it is always sorted, after every insert.

Comment: Thanks, any chance of a quick example? I'm struggling to find a good one.

Comment: something like    
    /* outside */
    multiset<string> stringSet;

                /* loading loop */
                while(!fin1.eof())
                {
                    string s;
                    fin1 >> s;
                    stringSet.insert(s);
                }

Comment: Please don't use `while(!in.eof())`, that will reuse the last result because only afterwards the streamstate will be EOF.

Comment: Ahh I did wonder why it gave out another repeat string, thanks, any suggestions for what else I could use? while(fin.good()) maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you can drop your requirement to sort the elements on the fly I suggest to use the following instead. Among others I have also changed the return type and decided not to close the `fstream`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "ArrayStorage.h"

std::vector<std::string> ArrayStorage::read(std::ifstream &fin)
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;

    std::string word;

    while (fin >> word)
    {
        words.push_back(word);
    }

    if (words.size() >= 2)
    words.erase(words.begin(), words.begin() + 2);

    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end());

    return words;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for taking the time to reply. Unfortunately its a requirement to use a dynamic array, no vector's, i appreciate the effort though!